# Как в модульный проект(android) добавить гугл аналитику?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Как в модульный проект добавить гугл аналитику? проблема в следующем в от гугл получаю google-services.json, это файл кидаю в мой проект, модуль проект ругает что у него нет google-services.json файла,  и еще вопрос через сколько приходит отчет?

Comment: я сам использовал бы Firebase Analytics, но сказали нужно гугл аналитику

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить в `Gradle` на уровне проекта:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Добавить в `Gradle` на уровне приложения:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //Для аналитики достаточно
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

Путь для *google-service.json* - `C:\Users\...\AndroidStudioProjects\...\app`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Обновляет раз в день

Answer (score 1):

Инфа прямиком с [оффициального сайта](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) также там проходясь по пунктам, набредешь на то как и устангвить в сам [проект](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start).

Также посоветовал бы рассмотреть [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) .

Ну и в заключении как вариант, можешь попробовать добавить две аналитики в свой проект, дабы иметь более точную картину происходящего.